# Error when import Middleware in a file

Tags: reactjs, import, redux, middleware

I have a middleware in a file middlewares/logger.js as following

```
  const logger = store => next => action => {
     console.log('dispatching', action)
     let result = next(action)
     console.log('next state', store.getState())
     return result
 }
```

And import and use it is as

```
 import {logger} from './middlewares/logger'
 ...
 let store = createStore(defaultReducers, applyMiddleware(logger));
```

I got the following error

Uncaught TypeError: middleware is not a function
      at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/static

But if I placed the logger inside the component where I used it and it worked

```
 const logger = store => next => action => {
     ...
  }

  let store = createStore(defaultReducers, applyMiddleware(logger));
```

Any suggestion about what was wrong?

thanks

Comment: `export const logger`, not `const logger`

Comment: yes.. missing export keyword as suggested above